# Does anybody know if The Japanese Embassy perform consular marriages in Spain?

Tags: eu, marriage, spain

And are they legal under EU and UK (and Japan, just to make it harder) Laws?

(This is part extension to a previous question but it has been virtually impossible to find the correct information online so far plus just to add for my new friend here, the embassies thus far do not wish to partake in giving out such useful information)

Comment: How about asking them?

Comment: wow! that probably wasn't worth the time to write, but i hope you amused yourself . Alas just to satisfy your bizarre take on life, judgement and assumption I have currently asked 3 different Embassies questions regarding the issue and so far received the usual automated response so thus far, they were in fact a little more helpful than yourself. Please do have a wonderful day won't you.

Comment: It is actually [recommended](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) that you include your previous research in the question in order to show other users what you have already tried. From that point of you, I think that @fkraiem's question is completely justified. Also please remember to [be nice](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), as people will be more inclined to help you if you don't bite them.

Comment: www.patronising.com

Answer (score 1):

For the 'legality' part of your question...

The UK and the other member states of the EEA are signatories in the [Convention of 14 March 1978 on Celebration and Recognition of the Validity of Marriages](http://www.hcch.net/index_en.php?act=conventions.text&cid=88) otherwise known as the [Hague Convention](http://www.hcch.net/upload/outline26e.pdf), or simply "Hague" when it refers to marriages.

This convention is an agreement that the signatories will treat a marriage (or divorce) as legal if it is treated as legal in the jurisdiction of where it was celebrated.

The UK interprets their part of the agreement as generally holding true EXCEPT where the marriage violates Part 1 of the [Marriage Act 1949](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Geo6/12-13-14/76/contents) (incestuous, too young, etc).

As trivia:  the UK (and EEA by agreement) also has some special opt-outs for corner cases none of which involve Japan or a Japanese national.

In cases where the celebration did not take place in a signatory country, the UK (and EEA by default) will use the [Doctrine of Comity](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/comity_of_nations) to recognize the marriage (as long as the country has viable diplomatic credentials).

Also, consular marriages are generally fine as long as they are not done over the phone (both parties and the celebrant are all together).